# how to implement pending upload to server android

Tags: android, file-upload

I am developing an application that using nojs as server and it's main function is upload image , video and note to server.

I want to take care about the situation when the user has limit bandwith or has no internet connection so I want all file in my app change status to pending and wait util user get back the internet connection .

here is my code in AsyncTask class upload

```
        File file = new File(imgPath);

        //Create the POST object
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);


        MultipartEntity entity = new MyMultipartEntity(new ProgressListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void transferred(long num)
            {
                //Call the onProgressUpdate method with the percent completed
                publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                Log.d("DEBUG", num + " - " + totalSize);
            }
        });
        //Add the file to the content's body
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody( file, "video/mp4" );
        entity.addPart("source", cbFile);

        //After adding everything we get the content's lenght
        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();

        //We add the entity to the post request
        post.setEntity(entity);

        //Execute post request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute( post );
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            //If everything goes ok, we can get the response
            String fullRes = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("DEBUG", fullRes);

        } else {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "HTTP Fail, Response Code: " + statusCode);
        }
```

any  idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a broadcast receiver that is called when the connectivity changes on the device.

When you receive the message you can check for any pending uploads and proceed (you'll need to implement this logic).

Your broadcast receiver needs to handle `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. How to do this is well document here on SO or a good place to start is [The Android Connectivity Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)